# Eror GraphQLDotNetCore C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4812

Tags: graphql

I have a project about using GraphQL for implementing my webservise,
when I want to build my project I get this error,

`Error  MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Users\test\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.protecteddata\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.     GraphQLDotNetCore   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  4812`

My visual studio is 2022 and I also have .net 6 and .net 5 in my project,,

Can anyone have same problem like me,
Whats the solution for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem with this error and finally I can solve this by adding and updating

> System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData

this package ,, as you can see in the below picture
[image]

after that you must rebuild your project and everything works fine for you.
share your result when testing my solution